# Cypress: browser authentication not working inside a custom command

Tags: cypress

I have a website which needs browser authentication on all page visits. If I use the below code on all page visits it works fine:

```js
describe('WW2-3461 validate patches for contrib modules and core', () => {        
  it('should visit my base URL', () => {
    
        cy.visit(Cypress.env('base_url'), {
    
          // Add basic auth headers
          auth: {
            username: Cypress.env('browserAuthentication').username,
            password: Cypress.env('browserAuthentication').password
          },
          failOnStatusCode: false
        })
      })
})
```

I am passing the `base_url` as an environment through CLI:

```js
npx cypress run --spec file.spec.js --env base_url=$base_url
```

I don't want to use `browserauthentication` on all page visits, so I created a custom command like below (in `integration/project/utility.js` file):

```js
  Cypress.Commands.add('addBrowserAuthentication', (url) => {
    cy.visit(url, {
    // Add basic auth headers
    auth: {
      username: Cypress.env('browserAuthentication').username,
      password: Cypress.env('browserAuthentication').password
    },
    failOnStatusCode: false
  })
})
```

However if I call this command inside a spec file, like below:

```js
import './utility.spec'

describe('WW2-3461 validate patches for contrib modules and core', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.addBrowserAuthentication(Cypress.env('cypress_host'))
  })
  it('should visit my base URL', () => {
    cy.visit(Cypress.env('cypress_host'), {
  })
})
```

the browser authentication does not seem to work (tried to call it inside `before()` hook or directly inside the test scenario) as it returns

```js
> 401: Unauthorized

This was considered a failure because the status code was not `2xx`.

This http request was redirected '1' time to:

  - 302: https://mysite.local

If you do not want status codes to cause failures pass the option: `failOnStatusCode: false`
```

I can't seem to work around this issue. Tried using `cy.request()` but getting the same issue. Has someone faced this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass env variable as a parameter, you can directly access it inside the custom command.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('addBrowserAuthentication', () => {
  cy.visit(Cypress.env('base_url'), {
    // Add basic auth headers
    auth: {
      username: Cypress.env('browserAuthentication').username,
      password: Cypress.env('browserAuthentication').password,
    },
    failOnStatusCode: false,
  })
})
```

And in your test directly use:

```js
cy.addBrowserAuthentication()
```

Also I am not sure if its required to visit the website two times. So you can remove  `cy.visit(Cypress.env('cypress_host')` if you are already using `cy.addBrowserAuthentication()`.

Answer (score 0):

Since this works

```js
cy.visit(Cypress.env('base_url'), {
    
  // Add basic auth headers
  auth: {
    username: Cypress.env('browserAuthentication').username,
    password: Cypress.env('browserAuthentication').password
  },
  failOnStatusCode: false
})
```

but this doesn't

```js
cy.addBrowserAuthentication(Cypress.env('cypress_host'))
```

it looks like `Cypress.env('cypress_host')` is not the same as `Cypress.env('base_url')`.

Everything else looks good in your command, so I'd try with

```js
cy.addBrowserAuthentication(Cypress.env('base_url'))
```

When you `cy.visit(Cypress.env('cypress_host')` without headers inside the test, the auth headers from `addBrowserAuthentication` are lost. I suggest removing that `cy.visit()`.